# Can a Hive custom SerDe produce multiple rows?

Tags: hive, apache-hive

I am using Hive 0.13.1 and I created a custom SerDe that is able to process a special kind of xml data. So far so good.
I also created a class for the InputFormat that splits the input data.

**Is it possible that I produce multiple rows (output) in the deserialize() function of my custom SerDe (or somewhere else in my SerDe)?**

So that I am able to create e.g. two rows out of one split?
In the deserialize function as far as I can see (in other SerDe classes), the return value is only a List (the values of one row) and that will be displayed as one row.

Lets say I have a xml like this:

```html
<item>
  <id>0</id>
  <timestamp>00:00:00</timestamp>
  <subitemlist>
    <subitem>1</subitem>
    <subitem>2</subitem>
  </subitemlist>
</item>
```

My SerDe gets the whole item block and what I want to do now is to create a row for each `<subitem>` with the id of `<item>` in Hive.

I can't adapt the InputFormat class because the problem is not as trivial as it is in this example :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The SerDe interface serializes/deserializes one record at a time because that's what serialization is supposed to do.
In general, it is not a good design decision to have a SerDe to actually transform data, that's what queries, UDFs and UDTFs are for.
The purpose of a SerDe is basically to map a data format to an equivalent hive schema.

I think the best way to do it is to have a table like

```
create table xmltable ( 
  id int,
  ts timestamp,
  subitems array<int>
)
```

using something with this [serde](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources)  and then create another table as a view

```
CREATE myview AS
  select id, sb FROM xmltable LATERAL VIEW explode(subitems) sb1 AS sb
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for your answer Roberto.

> In general, it is not a good design decision to have a SerDe to actually transform data, that's what queries, UDFs and UDTFs are for

Yeah probably you are right. The problem is that I need to do some processing based on the data of many columns. So a UDF would increase the complexity of this too much. But still, thanks for the answer.

I now solved it by adapting the next()-method in my InputFormat-class. (I know I said I didn't want to do this, but ...).
So I'm analysing the `<item>` tag and for every `<subitem>` I return the whole item to the SerDe.